# Trying to work around Firefox mixed content blocker

Tags: security, firefox, iframe

As many of us know, starting with version 23 Firefox blocks mixed content arguing it's unsafe. As a consequence iframes linking to external sites are no longer displayed(*). I tried the following settings in the config:

[image]

but this doesn't seem to help. I don't even get the warning (last setting). Are there other places in Firefox' `about:config` I should modify as well to get my iframes displayed?

(*)**edit**
This doesn't seem to happen always. iframes linking to amazon.co.uk don't work in Firefox, but when I try to add YouTube iframes they do embed the video correctly.

Comment: _“iframes linking to amazon.co.uk don't work”_ – that’s got nothing to do with the SSL problematic, but with amazon sending an `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` header, forbidding your browser to display their pages in any kind of frame that is not from the same domain.

Comment: @CBroe - The iframes are created by Amazon *itself* for Amazon Associates to include them on their sites, so the domain will always be different from Amazon's. It's not like Amazon wants to prevent use of iframes, rather the contrary. (Also note that they work in Chrome.) Thanks for your reply anyway.

Comment: Sorry, didn’t know you were talking about specific pages especially provided by amazon for this purpose (well, you didn’t). But if they do so, don’t they provide an HTTPS address to use for those already …?

Comment: @CBroe - sorry about the incomplete information. My page where I include the iframe is not an HTTPS address, nor is the src address in the iframe. (I don't know if the latter is relevant.) [This test page](http://stevenvh.net/test140324.php) displays properly in Chrome, but not in Firefox.

Comment: That test page displays the amazon iframe (“Kindle Fire HDX”) without any problem for me in Firefox – and if there’s no HTTPS involved at all, how would this even be a problem of mixed content blocking? Are you sure it’s not maybe rather some kind of extension (adblocker/privacy) that makes this not show up in just _your_ Firefox …?

Comment: @CBroe - I though about that, but I have the "amazon-adsystem.com" unchecked in Adblock Plus. Maybe I should uncheck other filters as well, but the "find" button in ABP doesn't work, so it's difficult to look for other Amazon filters.

Comment: Try [(re-)starting your Firefox in “safe mode”](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/troubleshoot-firefox-issues-using-safe-mode#w_how-to-start-firefox-in-safe-mode), without any add-ons enabled – different result?

Comment: @CBroe - It appears that Adblock Plus is indeed the culprit, not Firefox. BTW, you can disable it, so that I didn't have to restart in safe mode. It took me some time to find the pertaining filters, but when I disabled those I finally got to see the iframes. Thanks a bunch for your help.

Comment: I know that you can disable adblock ;-) – safe mode is just the quickest way to find out if _any_ of your extensions (might be many) is likely to blame or not …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, kudos to CBroe.

The config settings as shown in the question suffice as far as Firefox' security is concerned. The reason I didn't get to see Amazon's iframes was that they were blocked by Adblock Plus. I *had* already turned of one of the filters, but it appeared there were others as well. (This wasn't obvious because the "Find" function of Adblock Plus doesn't work, so I couldn't do a simple search for all Amazon filters.)